# Can washer / dryer waste water be routed into a shower drain?

Tags: drain

An office is to have a washer / dryer installed.   Options include installing washer:

1. next to water heater
2. by removing shower stall and replacing with heater

The latter has the advantage because the shower stall already has a water drain.  Is there any reason not to use the shower stall water drain for a washer / dryer?

Comment: Is there a reason to have a shower there, rinse off chemicals/medical?

Comment: Good question: No medical / chemical reason.

Comment: A home office?  Just seems odd that a business office would have a shower or need a washer/dryer.  Guess it is nice if you spill coffee on you.

Comment: The only problem I can think of would washing machines usually use a stand pipe for the drain so the pipe would need to be re routed. In a slab a bit of work, post and beam construction still some work but easier than a slab.

Comment: Should make this an answer, since it does answer the main question.

Comment: A typical pipework arrangement has a goal of handling backflow, siphoning and blockages - e.g. make sure that a hairball doesn't result in the washing machine filling the shower tray with waste water, and that running the machine doesn't result in the drain of the tray sucking air.